# Ammunition Depot: Monte Carlo Method

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, monte-carlo

I was given the following question from a friend of mine and I can't seem to understand it to well:

> A squadron of 10 bombers attempts to destroy an ammunition depot. The fighter jet flies in the horizontal direction. The aiming point is the center of the depot. The point of impact is assumed to be a normally distributed around the aiming point $(60,0)$ with a standard deviation $\sigma$ of $200$ yards in the horizontal direction and $100$ yards in the vertical direction. Simulate the operation and estimate the number of bombs on target.
>
> The middle two corners of the following ammunition depot are $(-150,0)$ and $(270,0)$. $X$~Normal (mean $= 60, \sigma = 200$) and $Y$~Normal (mean $=0,\sigma = 100$).

[image: Ammunition Depot]

The picture above is a diagram of the ammunition depot.

I don't have a strong background in statistics to fully understand how the normal distribution is being applied here. I am somewhat familiar with Monte Carlo Method, but I have only used it as an alternative to solving integrals numerically.

My idea was to just define the region above using the following equations: 
\begin{array}
` y_1 = 120 &  & -210\leq x \leq 210\\
y_2 = -120 &  & -210\leq x \leq 210\\
y_3 = 2x-540 &  & 210\leq x \leq 270\\
y_4 = -2x+540 &  & 210\leq x \leq 270\\
y_5 = 2x+300 &  & -210\leq x \leq -150\\
y_6 = -2x-300 &  & -210\leq x \leq -150\\
\end{array}
Then randomly generate points that represent where the projectiles land. If the projectiles (coordinates in this case) landed within the boundary I specified, then I would mark it as a hit; otherwise, a miss. However, I do not know if this is sufficient since it does not incorporate the distribution (at least not that I know of).

---

Thank you for your time and have a wonderful day.

Comment: Comment 1 - The direction of the bombers isn't specified. So you'll have to assume that they could be coming from any direction but headed on a vector over the center of the target.

Comment: Comment 2 - "a standard deviation σ of 200 yards in the horizontal direction and 100 yards in the vertical direction." X-Y on target. So the errors are not the same and if the target was a point then the errors would be an ellipse oriented by the direction of the flight of the bombers.

Comment: Comment 3 - Since the direction of the bombers is random, you can simply the error by calculating the radial error which will be symmetric. Thus you end up with a symmetric binormal distribution. This will be the Rayleigh distribution in polar coordinates. (This reduces variable space from 3 dimensions to 2).

Comment: @MaxW, Thank you for your feedback and contribution. It helps me understand the problem a little more.  Since the direction of the bombers is random, I want to conclude I can randomly generate coordinates and if these coordinates do not hit anywhere within my region of interest, I mark it as a miss. However, I do not know if this is sufficient since it does not incorporate the distribution. I'll continue to look into radial error and Rayleigh distribution in the meanwhile. Thank you once again for your feedback. I hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: Find center of target. Think in polar coordinates. Bombers can be coming from any angle. So angle is uniformly distributed.

Comment: @MaxW, Isn't the center of the target at (60,0)?. So our ellipse of interest is $\frac{(x-60)^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$: where $x=a\cos{\theta}+60$ and $y=b\sin{\theta}$. So depending on the angle $\alpha$ they are coming from, we can say they have a chance of hitting anywhere within the rotated ellipse: $\frac{(x\cos{\alpha}+y\sin{\alpha})^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y\cos{\alpha}-x\sin{\alpha})^2}{b^2}=1$?

Comment: Ok, thinking. I just realized that this is for one mission not an infinite number of missions (or randomized from any direction). I'm somewhat confused by "The fighter jet flies in the horizontal direction. "  I'm now reading that to mean "The squadron flies in the horizontal direction." which implies along the X axis to me. So one squadron attack from one specific direction.

Comment: So my comment 3 above is wrong. The gist is that changing to polar coordinates doesn't help here.

Comment: So my comments 1 and 3 above are both wrong. The gist is that changing to polar coordinates doesn't help here.

Comment: So you need to use two random numbers to get x and y errors from center of target. Then for that x-y position use a nasty bunch of tests to determine if the bomb falls within the target.

Comment: I was just about to say the overlapping ellipse form a circle centered around (60,0) but I guess that's irrelevant now. Haha. Thank you for pointing that out. I forgot about that small detail to be honest. Since we don't have to focus on these infinitely many different directions, I guess we can just focus on the on direction coming from the either the left or the right. That being said, are we only interested in points that fall within that one ellipse?

Comment: +Y and -Y are symmetric, so you can just consider +Y direction which reduces complexity.

Comment: The ellipse is sort of an imaginary 60% (?) confidence interval. Since the normal distribution goes to infinity, the bombs could drop a mile away.

Comment: Since the problem wants you to use Monte Carlo, you need to do this by using random number and then finding Z value from CDF of normal distribution function. // The other way to do this would be to do a numerical integration. Divide target into a bunch of X-Y squares and just integrate the solution. As the squares get smaller the answer would converge. The integration would give a much better value than a Monte Carlo approach.

Comment: @MaxW. Thank you.  My PDF was $\frac{1}{200\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{Exp}[\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{x-60}{200})^2]\frac{1}{100\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{Exp}[\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{y}{100})^2]$. To make a long story short, upon integrating over my region, the answer was approximately $0.5392$ or $53.92$%. However, Monte Carlo is required. I was able to randomly generate values for x and y using excel. I then got excel to output hit or miss depending whether or not it hit the target. I know Z value = (X - μ) / σ, however I am not sure how to incorporate it exactly.

Comment: You use a random number to get a value for the "percentile" of the CDF. So random number 0.05 corresponds to $-1.96 \sigma$.